# If $f$ is a non-constant elliptic function, then $z\mapsto f'(z)/f(z)$ is a non-constant elliptic function

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

How can I prove

> If $f$ is a non-constant elliptic function, then $z\mapsto f'(z)/f(z)$ is a non-constant elliptic function?

To prove that $z\mapsto f'(z)/f(z)$ is elliptic, it suffices to notice that
$$\frac{f'(z+\omega)}{f(z+\omega)}=\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$$
for any period $\omega$ of $f$.

But how can I prove that $f'(z)/f(z)$ is not a constant?

I observed that it fails for some periodic non-elliptic functions, for example if we choose $f=\exp$ then $f'(z)/f(z)$ is a constant.

Comment: $f'=cf$ implies $f(z)=ke^{cz}$ (first outside poles and then everywhere as is easily seen that if $g(z)=f(z)e^{-cz}$ then $g'=0$))

Comment: @Conrad I have no idea how is that related to my question.

Comment: Prove the contrapositive statement.

Comment: if $f'/f$ constant then there is $c$ st $f'=cf$ so $f$ is an exponential, hence $f$ being elliptic that is a contradiction

Comment: @Conrad I get it now.

Comment: happy to be of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f'/f$ is constant, then $f(z)=ke^{cz}$. Because every elliptic function free of poles must be constant, we conclude $c=0$ and $f(z)=k$. This proves the contrapositive version of the statement.